# Cron jobs in google cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron, google-compute-engine

I need to deploy few cron jobs for my nodejs app hosted on google cloud.

I have 2 options

- cron-schedule  npm package.
- cron.yaml provided by app engine.

I am not sure which has better performance and why ?

adding to it, I want my cron jobs to work on preemptible instance as they are meant for it, i search a lot but didn't find anything related.

Answer (score 1):

I can speak for cron.yaml.
1. Cron.yaml has timeout limit of 60 mins.
2. Cron.yaml has retry limit of 5
3. Cron are vm level so multiple apps with their own cron is out of question.
4. From fail or time out log entry doesn't include clear number of retry.

Comment: Thanks UPatel for reverting .. sry for late reply. I have already made my mind for cron.yaml . 1. undeploying cron job simply by editing cron.yaml.  2. monitoring on console and no doubt in that it is preferred by google on GAE.